# Dealing with function call syntax outside of function

Tags: function, call, walkthrough

I apologize if this is exceptionally elementary, but I just started programming in school, I have looked all over for the solution and unfortunately nothing has helped me with this.
I have this piece of code:

```
   #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>

int logic(int a, int b)
{
    int c = a % b;
    a++;
    b--;
    printf("==%d %d %d==\n", a, b, c);
    return b + a + c;
}

int main()
{
    int a, c;
    float d, f;
    a = 10;
    c = 5;
    f = 2;

    d = logic(a, logic(c, f));
    printf("%d %d %.2f %.2f\n", a, c, d, f);
    return 0;
}
```

Now the output for this is:

```
'== 6 1 1==
==11 7 2==
10 5 20.00 2.00'
```

Now the problem is how does the line `'d = logic(a, logic(c, f));'` compile in regards to the logic function above. I assume to get the first output, the logic function takes the value of 5 and 2 for c and f and runs it through the function for a and b. But I am totally stumped as to why the next output is `'==11 7 2=='`. What does return `'c + b + a;'` do exactly, when I replace the + operator with a comma only the first value in the output (which is 11 regardless of what order I place the variables) emerges, the rest are 0s.

Please help with this, I am incredibly stumped, have been at it for hours and still nothing.

Comment: I believe there's a missing piece of code. Might you please add it and better clarify where you don't get the understanding?

Comment: Nope thats everything. That exactly has the output of what is stated above.
I am trying to understand how the first output is 6 1 1, yet the second output is 11 7 2, I do not understand how the second output occurs.

Comment: Note that we're dealing with *two* sets of local variables here. The parameters of `logic()` are named `a` and `b`, but these names are *local* to `logic()` and have nothing to do with `a` and `b` declared in `main()`.

Comment: Okay... So care to explain, if the local values for main differ from the logic values, how does the output arrive with such answers.

Comment: Also note that the *output* comes from the `printf(...)` lines only. The `return b + a + c;` calculates the sum of b, a, and c, and returns that sum's value as the result of the function for further computing. So, to alter the appearance of the *output* on the screen, you have to change the `printf` lines, which is completely independent of the order in which the sum is calculated.

Answer (score 0):

> I assume to get the first output, the logic function takes the value of 5 and 2 for c and f and runs it through the function for a and b.

That is correct. What happens at first is equivalent to calling `logic( 5, 2 )`. Note two things: a) Inside the function `logic` we have a `printf` which prints some output to the screen, and b) the function `logic` *returns* a value of type `int`.
That's what the first `int` in `int logic(int a, int b)` indicates.

Now let's look at the original call:

`d = logic(a, logic(c, f));`

This tells the machine that we want to get the value returned by the function `logic` and store in in variable `d`. However, to call `logic` we need two int parameters. The first one is given as variable `a`, but to find the value for the second parameter a function needs to be executed first, which happens to be `logic` in this case.

This is just the same as in plain math: To calculate `f(g(x))` you'll have to first calculate `g(x)` and use the result as input for `f`. In a program, you could as well use another variable to store the intermediate result, like `int g_result = g(x); f( g_result );` This is completely equivalent.

So, to calculate the result of `logic(a, logic(c, f));`, `logic` needs to run *twice*. Every time `logic` is executed it runs across the `printf` and produces some output on the screen.

And that's why we get two lines of output "== ... ==", one for each run of the function `logic`.

As said above, you could just equivalently write:

```
int first_result = logic( c, f ); // This call produces the output of "== 6 1 1==" and returns the value 8 (= 6 + 1 + 1) which gets assigned to "first_result"

d = logic( a, first_result ); // This call produces the output of "==11 7 2==" from the function parameters "a" (=10) and "first_result" (=8).
```

Comment: Thank you a ton for this. First piece I have seen that has been thoroughly helpful!